# What's a good name for a circular buffer based queue that overwrote old data when full?

Tags: data-structures, computer-science

I need help choosing a good name for a queue that is based off of a circular buffer, overwrites old data and thus provides infinite storage.

If I named it just `Queue`, it wouldn't convey the important detail that "it overwrites old data when the storage is full and you push more items into it."

Generally, speaking, just the word `Queue` indicates a FIFO structure with a finite storage. So, I made a finite storage FIFO queue but based on a circular buffer, and just called it `Queue`.

Now, I want to name this infinite storage queue that internally has a limited storage circular buffer but it overwrites old data if the queue is full and  new data is pushed in.

Here's the internal debate going on in my mind:

**Contender:** `CircularBuffer / CyclicBuffer`
**Thoughts:** No. Well, may be. But shouldn't I tell them it is a queue? Are circular buffers used for anything else other than a queue? Besides, that's an implementation detail.

**Contender:** `CircularBufferBasedQueue`
Eee! Yuck! No!

**Contender:** `CircularBufferQueue`
**Thoughts:** Wrong English but forgiving that little anomaly, works pretty well. Ideally, in the .NET framework, if there were such an implementation, it would either be under a separate namespace but with the name just `Queue` (or `System.Collections.CircularBuffer.Queue`) that indicated this implementation details that it was based off of a circular buffer (if there were many other data structures based off of that, just like we have `SpecializedCollections`, `ConcurrentCollections`, `Collections.Generic`, and so on) or if a queue was the only one candidate that used circular buffers, it would be called `CircularBufferQueue` or `CircularBufferedQueue` (not sure what adding that little *ed* does to the meaning of the word).

One more thing I have against any name that starts with `CircularBufferXXX` is that having a circular buffer is an implementation detail and shouldn't therefore be a part of the name. It's like saying, `ArrayBasedLinkedList`.

But then again, having a circular buffer also conveys important behavior and not just an implementation storage detail. This behavior, if only left at the peril of the users of this data structure reading the documentation, could be the difference between life and death or good code and bad code.

**Contender:** `InfiniteStorageQueue`
**Thoughts:** Misleading. The storage isn't infinite. It is just that it overwrites old data so you can keep writing without having to worry about hitting a dead-end.

And if I named it `InfiniteStorageQueue`, should I then name the regular queue `FiniteStorageQueue`. Yuck! That just doesn't look alright.

How would you taxonomize this data structure?

Comment: That's an [LRU cache](http://mcicpc.cs.atu.edu/archives/2012/mcpc2012/lru/lru.html).

Comment: Interesting. Looking that one up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description sounds like the definition of a straight up circular buffer, I'm not sure why the unique naming. I would just call it `CircularBuffer`. Why?

1. Circular buffer is defined as having a fixed size.
2. Circular buffer is implemented as a queue data structure.
3. The standardized name is easily understandable and searchable.

However, if you did want a new name I would go with `OverwritingCircularBuffer`. Why?

1. We know that it's a circular buffer so it's fixed size.
2. We know that it will overwrite data from the name.
3. We know it will be a queue data structure.

Then of course add some pretty comments explaining how it works along with it's memory alloc size. :)

Comment: I ended up with `CircularBuffer`.